# JAVA - where to print out an integer, outside of while loop?

Tags: java, exception, printing, while-loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner beri = new Scanner(System.in);

        long vish = 16;         
        long shir = 29; 
        long n = 3; 

        long del1 = 0;
        long del2 = 0;
        long stranica1 = 0;
        long stranica2 = 0;

        long ostanek1 = 0;
        long ostanek2 = 0;
        long ostala_shir = 0;
        long plosce_shir = 0;
        long ostala_vish = 0;
        long plosce_vish = 0;
        long ploscice = 0;
        long del_dva = 0;
        long del_n = 0;

        long i = n;

        while (i <= n) {


            del_dva = 2;
            del_n = i;
            stranica2 = (long)Math.pow(del_dva, del_n);

            if (vish % stranica2 == 0 && shir % stranica2 != 0) {

                ostanek2 = vish % stranica2;
                ostala_vish = vish - ostanek2;
                plosce_vish = ostala_vish / stranica2;


                ostanek1 = shir % stranica1;
                ostala_shir = shir - ostanek1;
                plosce_shir = ostala_shir / stranica2;
                shir = ostanek1;

                ploscice = plosce_shir*plosce_vish;

            }
            i--;

        }
    }
}
```

The variables are in my language, but that doesn't affect my question.
Don't mind the initialization part, the variables aren't in english. 
***My question is:***  where in my program must I print out the result. I have already tried with ***for loop***, but for example the first time the program goes through the loop, the result is 6, then the next time the result it 4, then the next time 0 and the next time 16 ..

It prints out in this form: (the initial numbers are vish= **16**, shir = **29**, n =**3**)

- 6
- 4
- 0
- 16

.. what I would like to achieve is that it prints out **26** .. which in fact is (6+4+0+16)

.. and also sometimes java reports *Exception in thread main java.lang.ArithmeticException: /by zero*

Comment: Where is your print statement?

Answer (score 0):

You print it out after all calculation to get the right result are done.
In your case you have calculation of `stranica2` which can be null. You should check make a check 
`if (stranica !=0) { continue ;}`

The problem with your solution is that there is no end for `i`. `i` starts equal to `n` and goes down, the check in the while loop is also for numbers smaller than `n`, which means that you are having an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the sum like `sum += value;` in the loop and when the loop ends print the `sum`

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
// calculate value here

...

// now add the value in sum just before loop ends
sum += value
}

System.out.prinln("Total is " + sum);
```

and for `java.lang.ArithmeticException` ... This is because you are dividing some number by zero. In your example it is

```
if (vish % stranica2 == 0 && shir % stranica2 != 0) {

   ostanek2 = vish % stranica2;  // here ostanek2 = 0
   ostala_vish = vish - ostanek2;
   plosce_vish = ostala_vish / stranica2; // so here ostala_vish is divided by zero


   ostanek1 = shir % stranica1;
   ostala_shir = shir - ostanek1;
   plosce_shir = ostala_shir / stranica2;
   shir = ostanek1;

   ploscice = plosce_shir*plosce_vish;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner beri = new Scanner(System.in);

        long vish = 16;
        long shir = 29;
        long n = 3;

        long del1 = 0;
        long del2 = 0;
        long stranica1 = 0;
        long stranica2 = 0;

        long ostanek1 = 0;
        long ostanek2 = 0;
        long ostala_shir = 0;
        long plosce_shir = 0;
        long ostala_vish = 0;
        long plosce_vish = 0;
        long ploscice = 0;
        long del_dva = 0;
        long del_n = 0;

        long i = n;

        //declare and initialize the following variable named sum
        long sum = 0;

        //don't use i<=n since this is a decrementing loop. Use i >= 0 instead
        while (i >= 0) {

            del_dva = 2;
            del_n = i;
            stranica2 = (long) Math.pow(del_dva, del_n);

            if (vish % stranica2 == 0 && shir % stranica2 != 0) {

                ostanek2 = vish % stranica2;
                ostala_vish = vish - ostanek2;
                plosce_vish = ostala_vish / stranica2;

                ostanek1 = shir % stranica2; // you made a mistake here. 
                //If you write stranica1, then stranica1 = 0, 
                //and that's why you get the divide by zero exception
                ostala_shir = shir - ostanek1;
                plosce_shir = ostala_shir / stranica2;
                shir = ostanek1;

                ploscice = plosce_shir * plosce_vish;

            }

            //Do the following to get the sum of ploscice
            sum = sum + ploscice;
            i--;

        }
        //println should be outside the while loop. Same applies for for loop
        System.out.println("The sum is = " + sum);
    }

}
```

Although, I pretty much explained everything inside my code through inline comments, I'm going to go through the major problems in your code again.

**Firstly:**

Why did you use `i < = n` in while loop condition? You're decrementing the value of i, so this means it will become `i = 3`, then `i = 2`, then `i = 1` , then `i = 0`, then `i = -1` and so on, making it an infinite loop.

Use `i >= 0` instead. Thus the loop will end at `i = 0`

**Secondly:**

Since you're decrementing the value of `i`, so when it becomes `i = -1`, then `stravica2` value becomes 0. Hence, you get the divide by 0 exception because you're trying to get a modulus operation by dividing by `stravica2` inside your `if` condition

**Thirdly:**

You want to get the sum of `ploscice` after the while loop ends. However, you didn't declare any variable to hold the sum of `ploscice`.

So you need to declare a long variable named `sum`, initialize it to 0 before the while loop, then get the sum each time inside the loop by `sum = sum + ploscice`. Then print the sum **outside** the while loop.

Should get you the result:

```
10
```

Because, the `ploscice` values after each iteration in the loop are:

- 6
- 4
- 0
- 0 (not 16)

Result is 10.

**Last but not the least:**

Why did you do this?

```
ostanek1 = shir % stranica1;
```

Isn't `stranica1` equals 0? How come you'll get `ostanek1` value? It will give you that divide by zero exception.

Fix it to this:

```
ostanek1 = shir % stranica2;
```